# Differentiable function with nowhere differentiable derivitive

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if it there is a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable everywhere, but with a derivitive that is nowhere differentiable.

Comment: You could integrate the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look up your favorite example of a continuous-but-nowhere differentiable function, then integrate it. By the fundamental theorem of calculus you'll get the original function back when you differentiate.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Nowhere_Differentiable_Function

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is. Let $g$ be the Weierstrass function, and put
$$
f(x)=\int_0^x g(t)dt.
$$
Then $f$ is everywhere differentiable because it is an integral of a continuous function. But $f'=g$, which is nowhere differentiable.

Comment: Beaten to the punch! +1

Comment: Oh, right. That's pretty cool. Thanks